# why result shows some grade value as null

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

```
SELECT
    `job_id`,
    CASE `job_id`
    WHEN  'AD_PRES' THEN 'A'
    WHEN 'ST_MAN' THEN 'B'
    WHEN 'IT_PROG' THEN 'C'
    END AS 'grade'
FROM
    `employees`
WHERE
    'grade' IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: WHERE    'grade' IS NOT NULL; - I'm not clear what you are testing here is grade a column in employees if so it should be backticked rather than single quoted , as is the string grade is never null..and does not refer to the column aliased as 'grade' in the select.

Comment: thanks for answering,but grade is the alias of the case function,I tried backticked and it still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes in MySQL denote string literals.  For database identifiers, such as column or table names, use double quotes, backticks, or nothing at all, if not required.  Here you don't need to escape the alias.  In addition, you generally cannot refer to an alias in the `WHERE` clause.  But, MySQL has overloaded its `HAVING` operator to allow it to refer to an alias.  Putting this all together, we can use this version:

```sql
SELECT job_id,
       CASE job_id WHEN 'AD_PRES' THEN 'A'
                   WHEN 'ST_MAN'  THEN 'B'
                   WHEN 'IT_PROG' THEN 'C'
       END AS grade
FROM employees
HAVING grade IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that you could also phrase this as:

```sql
SELECT job_id,
       CASE job_id WHEN 'AD_PRES' THEN 'A'
                   WHEN 'ST_MAN'  THEN 'B'
                   WHEN 'IT_PROG' THEN 'C'
       END AS grade
FROM employees
WHERE job_id IN ('AD_PRES', 'ST_MAN', 'IT_PROG');
```

This also works because `grade` would only be non `NULL` if the `job_id` were one of these three values.